# Quarkus GraphQL not using my Jackson ObjectMapperCustomizer

Tags: graphql, quarkus

I configure my `ObjectMapper` as follows:

```
    objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(SNAKE_CASE);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(NON_EMPTY);
```

How do I make GraphQL use my customized mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson is not supported in SmallRye GraphQL. There is an issue open to add support for Jackson annotations, I suggest to comment there and add this requirement. see https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql/issues/860